# Mocking a Set matcher in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a library that checks if the object is an instance of a class by using the following expression

`ClassName === object`

Is there any way to write a `double` that can mock this such that the expression above(where my double would replace the object in expression) returns true

Comment: Is `object` of type `Set`?

Comment: `allow(ClassName).to receive(:===).with(object).and_return(true)` should do the trick if you can't use an actual instance of `Set`.

Comment: Can you share the way you're using this lib in your specs? There are at least few possible ways to achieve that, but it depends on how you're using it.

Comment: @Stefan, can you please move your comment to an answer so that I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `ClassName === object` is equivalent to `object.kind_of?(ClassName)`, Ruby checks the object's class without calling any of `object`'s methods. This means `object` can't do anything in this situation to be recognized as a `ClassName` instance, unless of course it actually *is* an instance of `ClassName` (or one of its subclasses / included modules).

However, `ClassName === object` is nonetheless a method call. So what you *can* do is stubbing the `===` method on `ClassName`:

```
allow(ClassName).to receive(:===).with(object).and_return(true)
```

The above even works for:

```
case object
when ClassName
  # ...
end
```

which simply invokes `ClassName === object`.

Comment: Do you know something about the `&` method in `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`?